# multi master replication

Tags: mysql, replication

Let us say I have a master(m) slave(s) replication. Now, in the scheme of things, I introduce another database/schema(foo) not associated with the master in any way and I want this schema to be replicated into the slave(s). Can I do this?

AFAIK, this cannot be done. What is the best way to pull this off? The reason I want to do this is I want to join tables from foo with s/m.

The data replication need not happen in real time, can be a daily cron job too. Is mysqldump the way to go? Is there some hack that I can pull off?

Comment: mysql 5.7 have this feature now. A slave can have more than one master.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way, but you can always pull the binary log and let it execute somewhere else.

A MySQL node can be Master AND Slave at the same time, but it cannot be Slave of two Masters.

See this similiar post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576603/is-it-possible-to-do-n-master-1-slave-replication-with-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question many times before

- `Apr 25, 2011` : [**MySQL in Star Topology**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5781504/491757) (1st Answer StackOverflow)
- `Apr 26, 2011` : [**MySQL in Star Topology**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5784578/491757) (2nd Answer StackOverflow)
- `Apr 28, 2011` : [MySQL in Star Topology](https://serverfault.com/a/264444/69271) (ServerFault)
- `Aug 29, 2011` : [MySQL Replication : 1 Slave / Multiple Masters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/mysql-replication-1-slave-multiple-masters/5174#5174)
- `Feb 03, 2012` : [One slave, multiple masters MySql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12178/one-slave-multiple-masters-mysql/12179#12179)
- `Jan 21, 2013` : [Change the Existing Topology of a MySQL Replication Setup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33257/change-the-existing-topology-of-a-mysql-replication-setup/33296#33296)
- `Apr 18, 2013` : [Single slave - multiple master MySQL replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40379/single-slave-multiple-master-mysql-replication/40382#40382)

Here is what you need to do to implement it:

- You need to record each master's current log file and position
- You need to round-robin connect the Slave to each Master

  - `STOP SLAVE;`
  - `CHANGE MASTER TO <information for the next Master>;`
  - `START SLAVE;`
- Keep in mind the MySQL can only do `CHANGE MASTER TO` command using a single host

## ALTERNATIVE : MariaDB (Warning : Alpha Release right now)

As a radical alternative, you could upgrade to MariaDB because they have what is called [**multisource replication**](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/multi-source-replication/). [MariaDB reworked CHANGE MASTER TO command](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/change-master-to/) to set up an I/O thread to point to a different master. Think of it: multiple I/O threads is exactly the implementation needed for true multimaster replication.

**CAVEAT** : I would worry a lot about this because if two or more Masters try to update the same table, you will get deadlocks. I would setup these multiple masters and replicate specific databases per I/O thread to avoid table deadlocks.

In other words, note this example:

- You have three databases : db1, db2, and db3
- Run the Following on the Slave

  - Setup `CHANGE MASTER TO 'io1'` for `db1` from `server1`
  - Setup `CHANGE MASTER TO 'io2'` for `db2` from `server2`
  - Setup `CHANGE MASTER TO 'io3'` for `db3` from `server3`
- Write all changes to `db1` on `server1`
- Write all changes to `db2` on `server2`
- Write all changes to `db3` on `server3`
- Do not write changes to `db1` on `server2` or `server3`
- Do not write changes to `db2` on `server1` or `server3`
- Do not write changes to `db3` on `server1` or `server2`

If you follow this exact paradigm, then MariaDB can provide what you need.

Comment: Deadlocks when multiple masters update the same table isn't a concern with MariaDB 10.0 because you cannot replicate the same table in the same schema from more than 1 master, at all. That doesn't work, in much the same way conventional replication fails when master and slave tables aren't identical... try to delete or update a missing row and the slave SQL thread stops the show.  Two masters can have the same schema names, as long as there are no overlaps in table name. (e.g. in my setup here, both masters have an `accounting` db, but by dumb luck, the two masters have no same-named tables).