# Single slave - multiple master MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I need to replicate different MySQL databases from multiple servers into a single slave server. How can this be done? is there a way to define multiple master hosts?

Answer (score 5):

As of October 2013 MySQL (> 5.7.6) supports multi-source replication.

[MySQL Multi-Source Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html) in MySQL Reference Manual

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/02/mysql-5-7-multi-source-replication/

http://on-mysql-replication.blogspot.com/2013/09/feature-preview-mysql-multi-source-replication.html

Answer (score 4):

I answered this controversial question back on Feb 03, 2012 : [One slave, multiple masters MySql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12178/one-slave-multiple-masters-mysql/12179#12179)

By design, a Slave cannot be a Slave to Multiple Masters. Why? The command [**CHANGE MASTER TO**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/change-master-to.html) only allows one MASTER_HOST parameter.

## APPROACH #1

If each Master have a distinct Database that is mutually exclusive from other Master, you could have a Slave be a Slave to just one Master. Then, when all changes are posted, you would stop replication, run `CHANGE MASTER TO` command to point the Slave at a different Master. Then, run `START SLAVE`. I explained this setup in [MySQL in star topology (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5784578/491757).

The drawback to this approach would simply be the bookkeeping. This would require

```
STOP SLAVE;
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

and recording `Master_Host`, `Relay_Master_Log_File` and `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` from each Master and simply doing a round-robin from Master to Master. When you reach the next Master, you would take the previously recorded `Master_Host`, `Relay_Master_Log_File` and `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` and running

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
    MASTER_HOST='...',
    MASTER_LOG_FILE='...',
    MASTER_LOG_POS=...
;
START SLAVE;
```

## APPROACH #2

According to [the book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101716)

[image: sdocns]

Pages 373-375 has two diagrams of three DB Servers (M1, M2, S1)

### DIAGRAM #1

- M1 has the following characteristics

  - Slave of M2
  - Database db1 has real data
  - Database db2 all tables use [**BLACKHOLE Storage Engine**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html)
- M2 has the following characteristics

  - Slave of M1
  - Database db1 all tables use [**BLACKHOLE Storage Engine**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html)
  - Database db2 has real data
- S1 has the following characteristics

  - Slave of M2
  - Database db1 has real data
  - Database db2 has real data

### DIAGRAM #2

- M1 has the Database db1
- M2 has the following characteristics

  - Slave of M1
  - Database db1 all tables use [**BLACKHOLE Storage Engine**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html)
  - Database db2 has real data
- S1 has the following characteristics

  - Slave of M2
  - Database db1 has real data
  - Database db2 has real data

**WARNING** : As long as you do not run `ALTER TABLE` statements against a database that is made up of all `BLACKHOLE` tables, this approach is the closest you can get to Single Slave/Multiple Master Replication. You will have to live with possible latency issues.

Comment: I believe MySql now supports multi-source replication. Someone needs to update this answer.

Comment: This answer does not contain information about which version it applies to. With 5.7+ the answer seems to be different

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, MySQL does not support multisource replication (a replica with more than one master). However, you can emulate this topology by:

- either changing the replica to point at different master in turn
- or using master-master replication and the Blackhole storage engine with a replica

Take a look at [this](http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=D0b_Xg3UeXEC&pg=PA480&lpg=PA480&dq=%22emulating+multisource+replication%22&source=bl&ots=RZRj1QFCTF&sig=hkKpTvRNRaFAvS6qhHCYLFqVKm4&hl=vi&sa=X&ei=xyBwUYuhG66TiQeYlIGoAQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22emulating%20multisource%20replication%22&f=false) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a native solution in MySQL to support multiple masters, but there are some theoretical alternatives:

**Option 1.** MariaDB 10, which has everything in MySQL 5.5, some things from MySQL 5.6, and some new things.  This version is currently still in Alpha, but supports a single slave replicating continuously from multiple masters using [Multi-Source Replication](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/multi-source-replication/).

**Option 2.** MyISAM tables can theoretically be shared among multiple MySQL instances on the same machine, so it's possible -- on one machine -- to create an individual MySQL instance for each machine you need to replicate from, and then one more instance that is able to see those tables through creative use of symlinks.  This would work even if the tables on the masters aren't MyISAM, as long as you prevent the tables from being altered in a way that would break the setup.

**Option 3.** Depending on your needs, you could set up multiple slaves on the same machine and expose the tables on "Slave B" to queries on "Slave A" by declaring federated tables on Slave A that connect to Slave B.  With the two instances on the same machine, the `FEDERATED` queries are very responsive.  I use this in a setup where I have reports that rely heavily on joining data from two disparate and otherwise-disconnected systems.

The important thing to remember about federated connections is that if you issue a query that requires a full table scan, the entire contents of the federated table will have to be transferred between the two servers for each query, so I typically tell the server where the federated table is defined that *every* column in the federated table has its own index, in addition to the real indexes existing on the server where the data physically exists.  (Federated indexes are only logical, they do not take up space).  This almost always prevents the optimizer from choosing a full table scan.